# When coding a Java class in Eclipse, is it possible to insert a URL hyperlink to a webpage..?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am coding a Java class in Eclipse. In some commented lines, I would like to insert clickable URL hyperlinks that point to web pages on the internet.

Note: This is not a JavaDocs document, it's a regular .java class file.

Is this possible..?

If so, how..?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no standard way to do this. Some editors may make it clickable. Some won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, you can paste the link to a comment, hold down control and click it.
If you want to be able to just press it without holding anything down, go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Hyperlinking, then click on URL and remove the modifier key, click apply, click ok and you're done!

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly for me, but if I send the code to someone else, they'd have to make the same change. Based on the other answer from Frankenapps, I've added the note "CTRL+hover to activate link". It's simpler than explaining the preferences change. But I did make the change in my own preferences; I like it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is by simply pasting the link in the comment. When the user presses CTRL and hovers the mouse over the link, it becomes a valid hyperlink and can be opened in browser by clicking at it.

EDIT: If it does not work in the beginning search for "hyperlinking" in the comments.